# Is there a web button for Stack Overflow?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow

I really like Stack Overflow and I want to support it by putting a web button on my blog that links to SO. Has anyone designed one?

I tried to design it myself but the text "stackoverflow" didn't fit in a 80x15 web button such as:
[image: Play OGG!]
[image: Hacker]

Comment: Whoa... web buttons... looking to the past as we enter a new year?

Comment: I find it funny that the text overflows :)

Answer (score 10):

The closest I could get in 80x15

[image: SE Web Button]

Answer (score 6):

This is quite an old post, but I think [User Flair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair) is what you were looking for.